# How to create plan on stripe and return plan id with prefix plan_

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am creating a plan with Stripe, but the returned id is prefixed with plan_ `(plan_JpCO5hQmxIMCJS)`  not price_ `(price_JpCO5hQmxIMCJS)` like on the document, tell me why and how to fix it, thanks.
This is data return in document stripe

```
{
  "id": "price_1JDP7V2eZvKYlo2Ci6hxmkDV",
  "object": "plan",
  "active": true,
  "aggregate_usage": null,
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_decimal": "2000",
  "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
  "created": 1626334593,
  "currency": "usd",
  "interval": "month",
  "interval_count": 1,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "nickname": null,
  "product": "prod_Jr66HgcAtDZEOI",
  "tiers_mode": null,
  "transform_usage": null,
  "trial_period_days": null,
  "usage_type": "licensed"
}
```

Comment: There maybe a copy/paste issue when writing documentation of Plan and Price

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc no, i see api return plan.

Comment: So you call Plan API and it return plan_ in id?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc yes

Comment: As I mentioned, there maybe a mistake when writing the doc of Plan API. Maybe they copy it from Price API and forget to change price_ to plan_

Comment: It doesn't matter really, you can use a Plan anywhere that expects a Price, and vice versa, so I wouldn't worry about it too much unless you actually get an error trying to use the object. (see the grey box at the top of https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide for example)